# Is it possible that ADB communicate with 3rd party Android AIDL?

Tags: android, kotlin, adb, aidl

Android can use `adb shell service call SERVICE` to communicate with .aidl file, pass arguments and get return value. However, it belongs Android source code. Is it possible I can do the same thing after install non-system app which is written by myself?

For example, I write an app which its package name is `com.test.aidl` and there is a function inside.

```
fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return x +y
}
```

Can I use adb command, such as `adb shell service call com.test.aidl add i32 1 i32 2` and get value `3` on command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this using instrument.

ADB command

```
adb shell am insrument -e <NAME> <VALUE> <package/runner>
```

Android

```
public class Test extends android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);
        value = (String) bundle.get("name");
}
```

Then use ***sendStatus api*** to print on CMD.

Comment: Can you please add sendStatus api code also.